# Where's a good place to learn how to do good UI?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, uiview

My company is smaller. So unfortunately, we don't have the budget to afford a good (or bad) UI designer/developer. So we do programmer's UI. As you can imagine, it gets us by but it's not good at all.

Well what I'm looking for is a good resource that shows or explains how to have good layout and intuitive control placement in an Web app (or even Desktop app). Are there any tutorials or web sites that any of you would suggest?

Comment: Here's an MS resource for Windows 7 (I know you've said asp.net but this is pretty good for forms apps) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx

Comment: honestly, I'm a fan of Mozilla's early learning material.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn  There are UI best practices  references in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some help about software UI , Apple wrote this doc', i think it could be a good beginning : 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000894-TP6

More generally you can also throw a look at these websites : http://sixrevisions.com/usabilityaccessibility/20-websites-to-help-you-master-user-interface-design/

http://dzineblog.com/2010/03/best-user-interface-design-resources-the-round-up.html

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Information Architecture. This will give you some understand behind the science of UX/UI which will in turn help you design your UI. I am a programmer myself, and have only read a few books but I now understand the impact of design. Especially since to your users, the UI **is** the application.
For example, there are some defined ways on which a user interacts with a site - browse, search, and interactive. A site should accomodate all because each user has different preferences.

[IA Institute Reading List](http://www.iainstitute.org/en/learn/education/recommended_reading.php)

[The Humane Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Humane_Interface) - this book can get very detailed talking about how many clicks someone has to do to perform a task, but this makes a huge impact if they have to do it all day long!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to design and UI then you should take a look at Microsoft's Toolbox site. It helps you learn the design principles and do design practicals using Microsoft Expression Studio (a UI prototyping tool). Check out the site here: [Microsoft Design Toolbox](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/)